# ¿Cómo poner un auto limite en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, autoincremento

Estoy haciendo un programa en MySQL Front con junto a un PLC Haiwell, ya me esta leyendo datos pero deseo que cuando el *auto_increment* llegue a 100 se borre e inicie desde 0 automáticamente y siga con la lectura [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Lo otro: mysql font? Será mysql front?

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda, soy algo nuevo en MySQL y pues ando basando todo en videos y pues a prueba y error mía

Comment: No hay lío. Revisa los enlaces que te recomendé. Lo otro: es importante que compartas la forma como estás definiendo la tabla. ¿Por qué? Porque, si lo reinicias al llegar a 100 y tu campo tiene un índice (es llave primaria, por ejemplo), va a fallar la inserción porque intentas insertar un valor repetido. Prueba explicando mejor tu necesidad

Answer (score 0):

Pues debe ser algo así:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER borrar BEFORE INSERT ON tutabla FOR EACH ROW SET valor = 0 when 
valor = 100;
```

Mira la documentación https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Si esto es complemento de tu otra publicación entonces por favor considera que deberían ir unidas, pues dada la extensión de las mismas no hace sentido que permanezcan como *doble respuesta* ya que en una de tus *respuestas* le dices que debería usar y luego en otra el como hacerlo.